# EF mapping issues

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I am a beginner to Entity Framework. In my project, I'm following a model-first approach, I created my tables and the associations between them, like in this screenshot:

For the Visual Studio mapping always takes the KF into account even if I don't ask.

Can someone help me overcome this problem?
below the code of the two entities

```
public partial class Currencies
{
    [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2214:DoNotCallOverridableMethodsInConstructors")]
    public Currencies()
    {

    }
```

Thank you !

Comment: Hi Chaymae, Welcome to SO, Can you share the code here instead of the Images

Comment: Please take a look here -> https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: And if you're just getting started with EF, you might want to start with the more modern "code-first from an existing database" workflow, instead of the designer-based database-first.  See eg: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/ef6/modeling/code-first/workflows/existing-database

Comment: HEY I HAVEN't a code bcz it s model first ans it s not my choise :(

Comment: Im unable to display the images, could you please share your codes? :)

Comment: Im sorry but i do not have code, im working with model first

Comment: What made you using model-first approach? You should do code-first approach to control, i.e. you should first make a model in database and only then reflect it in EF.

Comment: they told me to strat with model(model first) , not my choice

Comment: Side note but you probably want to change that table and property name to Currency (singular), not Currencies.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> help me overcome this problem

which problem?  This is how EF is supposed to work.

If you really want to query it yourself later, without an FK index, then replace the `Currencies` property with an `Guid CurrencyId` in ExchangeRate.

Comment: My probleme is in the mapping, for exemple in ExchangeRate table like u see there is no mapping for IdCurrencies

Comment: Normally EF does adds a key column without mapping it to a property. You could add it yourself, I think. Long time since I used that designer.

Comment: no , I can't add it  :(

Comment: Why not? It's just another column/property. What is stopping you?

Comment: for exemple  in the scrool bar of  mapping ExchangeRate i can't find the colums of Currencie and VS

Comment: I see `Currencies_IdCurrencie` which is a column but not a property.

Comment: But I still don't see what the problem is. Maybe you just have the wrong expectations? Be clear about what you want to do and what doesn't work.

Comment: ok what i want to do is having the association(mapping) btw entities just virtual that s mean in the table of mapping above i must no have the primarykey of currency in exchange rate .

Comment: That is not a "want to do". This is just how EF works, I still see no problem. It's an unmapped foreign key, no problem. If you don't want it, remove ExchangeRates from Currency.

Comment: In your code that is remove ExchangeRate from Currencies. But you should fix those names.

Comment: okey, i will see perhaps it s just what i expect, anyways thank you so much for ur answers.